# Different background colours using four colours in a pattern

Tags: jquery, css, colors

I have a set of four colours and I'm wondering if it's possible to change the colour of a div in pattern using these four colours as a loop. So, for example:

div1 = red
div2 = blue
div3 = green
div4 = yellow
[starts over]
div5 = red
div2 = blue
div3 = green... and so on.

I'm thinking jQuery/JS would be best. I tried using nth-childs etc but there not quite that robust.

Any help?

Thanks,
R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with just CSS:

```
div:nth-child(4n+1) { background-color : red; }
div:nth-child(4n+2) { background-color : blue; }
div:nth-child(4n+3) { background-color : green; }
div:nth-child(4n+4) { background-color : yellow; }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RLmgD/

But if you really want jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div:nth-child(4n+1)").css("background-color","red");
    $("div:nth-child(4n+2)").css("background-color","blue");
    $("div:nth-child(4n+3)").css("background-color","green");
    $("div:nth-child(4n+4)").css("background-color","yellow");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RLmgD/1/

Comment: @Adil - That's not colourful. [_This_](http://jsfiddle.net/RLmgD/3/) is colourful...

Comment: Yup, looking good. I wish I could give more up for unshift with pop, brilliant.

Comment: What if we using index manipulation instead of unshift and popup would that be more efficient? As unshift and pop change the length of array causes memory allocation and deallocation?

Comment: @Adil - I did the unshift and pop thing because I wanted a simple one-liner, but as far as efficiency I don't think it matters for such a small array and a 400ms interval - clarity in the code wins out. However, in a "real" implementation I would not have had four `.css()` statements in a row with hardcoded array indexes, I would've used a loop and probably some sort of caching of jQuery objects, and once I had a loop that would make it easier to do index manipulation like you suggest.